# Changed MaximumErrorCount to 9999 but still getting an error that says it is set to 1

Tags: ssis

I am running an SQL task, though whenever it runs it stops and gives me the error:

"...the number of errors raised (50) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure"

Despite the fact that I set the MaximumErrorCount in the properties for this and all other tasks in the package to 9999. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The package will fail even if all the tasks have the MaximumErrorCount set to 9999 as the package itself needs the MaximumErrorCount set to a higher number other than 1. If the package has the MaximumErrorCount property set to a higher number, it can return a success result even if the tasks inside it fail.

Be sure that if a task is expected to fail, then for dependent task you use a precendence constraint with a Completion Value rather than a success value, if you want them to run after the 1st task is attempted.